# Codeigniter: How to include SUM() and COUNT() in JOIN query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this method in my Model

```
function get_users_details(){
        $this->db->select("a.*,sum('b.downloads') as downloads,COUNT('b.user_email') as uploads");
        $this->db->from('user a');
        $this->db->join('files b', 'a.email = b.user_email','inner');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        $query->free_result();
        return $data;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It only returns values from a single row while actually it supposed to return values from multiple rows.

Comment: Correct this line - `$this->db->select("a.*,sum(`b.downloads`) as downloads,COUNT(`b.user_email`) as uploads");`

Comment: How should it be written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sum() and count() are aggregate functions and will only return 1 row unless you combine it with a group_by statement.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_a
```

will return the total number of rows in table_a.

```
SELECT table_a.email, count(*) FROM table_a GROUP BY table_a.email
```

will return the total number of rows PER email address.

In codeigniter 3, we use

`$this->db->group_by("table_a.email");`